# union in c stores one data at a time

Tags: c++, c, unions

If size of the union allocated in memory is equal to the biggest data type member in bytes then could anyone tell me how compiler is storing and fetching two datas double d and int i (total 8+4 bytes) (double on my machine is of 8 bytes) .

```
#include<stdio.h>
union test {

    int i;
    double d;

};

int main()
{
   union test obj;
   obj.d=15.5;
   obj.i=200;

   printf("\nValue stored in d is %f",obj.d);
   printf("\nValue stored in i is %d",obj.i);
   printf("\n size of obj is %d ",sizeof(obj));

}

**Output is : Value stored in d is 15.500000
Value stored in i is 200
 size of obj is 8**
```

Comment: Because members of the union occupy the same memory region with the smaller members occupying only a portion it.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious : int i takes 4 bytes double d takes 8 bytes alone .. and size of obj(union) is 8 bytes then how compiler is storing and retrieving the value .. I didn't understand what you said

Comment: are you asking about c or c++? in c, it is defined behavior afaik if the corresponding bit pattern yields a valid `int`. in c++ it definitely is undefined behavior.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb  Why is so that here in `c` it has defined behaviour ?

Comment: @theartist33: You are simply printing your `d` with insufficient precision, which is why you don't see the damage done by that `200`. That `200` destroyed part of your `d`, but it just happened to be on the least significant end of `d`. Rounding in `printf` hides the damage. Print with `%.20f` and you will see it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way it can store both is "pure luck". I'm just going to assume your computer architecture uses IEEE 754 floating point numbers and try to explain what you're seeing. Your union really does use only eight bytes, but 15.5 looks like this in hex: `402F000000000000`. As you can see the lower four bytes are completely zero. Now let's set the lowest four bytes to an integer 200 and see what happens to the eight byte value. That gives us `402F0000000000C8`. Now say you read all eight bytes back as a double now, in IEEE754 you get `15.500000000000355` which when printed will round off to 15.5 making it appear that the union can store both a double and an int.

All that said accessing both members of the union like that is undefined behavior in C++ at least up to C++11 (even though it behaves in the logical way on all platforms I'm aware of), so this is simply one possible explanation for the behavior you observe. In C it appears to be completely legal though.

Comment: "All that said accessing both members of the union like that is undefined behavior" Great answer until here. Accessing members of a union of a different type from the last one assigned is explicitly allowed by the C99 and C11 standards, and implementation defined (not undefined) in C89.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it seems like you can store both numbers in overlapping memory is the way the representation of the small values you chose is arranged.

If you try values that require more information stored like for example:

```
obj.d=100000000000000;
obj.i=0xffffffff;
```

You'll see a difference in the output of printing the `double` value:

```
Value stored in d is 100000059097087.984375
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not really working the way you think it is. If you add a bit more to the test:

```
#include<stdio.h>
union test {
    int i;
    double d;
};

int main()
{
   union test obj;
   obj.d=15.5;
   obj.i=200;

   printf("\nValue stored in d is %f",obj.d);
   printf("\nValue stored in i is %d",obj.i);
   printf("\n size of obj is %d ",sizeof(obj));

   obj.d=17.5;

   printf("\nValue stored in d is %f",obj.d);
   printf("\nValue stored in i is %d",obj.i);
   printf("\n size of obj is %d ",sizeof(obj));

   obj.i=300;

   printf("\nValue stored in d is %f",obj.d);
   printf("\nValue stored in i is %d",obj.i);
   printf("\n size of obj is %d ",sizeof(obj));

}
```

Output is:

```
$ ./main 

Value stored in d is 15.500000
Value stored in i is 200
 size of obj is 8 
Value stored in d is 17.500000
Value stored in i is 0
 size of obj is 8 
Value stored in d is 17.500000
Value stored in i is 300
 size of obj is 8
```

Note that value of i is 0 in the middle there! That's because it got (partially?) overwritten.

If I understand correctly it's undefined behavior there, and exactly what value you see will depend on the architecture you compile it for, the alignment the compiler uses for this structure etc. etc.

Edit:

I think I understand the original question now -- it's about, why is it possible to recover the first stored value at all, right? Why don't I see gibberish instead of 200.

My guess is that it might depend on some implementation details of the floating point stuff? Maybe the double happens not to overwrite the bits of "int" if its a "simple" double like 17.5. Not completely sure. Edit: See "imreal"'s answer.

Comment: I think too this is undefined behavior where we can expect it to work as well .

Comment: :your edit and assumption is not correct .. what you said earlier was right instead . what could have happend was compiler first stored d then it overwrites d space with integer i . Somehow value of d (bits ) could not completely overwritten while storing 200 as int and thus both i and d in this case was able to be retrieved by compiler with luckily exact value (Welcome to the world of Undefined Behavior ) . Agree ? @Mark B

Comment: yes I agree, what I wrote would have made more sense if i was written first and then d. it's about the value of d (bits) that is printed and why *that* is not gibberish. i think though that the reason that it works is that when the machine writes 17.5 to d, it doesn't actually overwrite all the double bits, only the bits that it needs for, for speed I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can store either `i` or `d` to your union, not both at the same time. The statement

```
obj.i=200;
```

overwrites the value stored at the memory allocated for the union. Now accessing `obj.d` with `%f` specifier will invoke undefined behavior that's because the value stored in `obj` is `int`.

Answer (score 1):

After writing to `obj.i`, reading from `obj.d` is undefined behavior, and as far as the C standard is concerned anything can happen.

In this particular case you probably don't *see* anything happen because of floating point numbers are laid out in memory. You are changing some of the least significant bits of the mantissa, creating a change that's not seen in the first 6 decimal digits. Add more digits:

```
printf("\nValue stored in d is %.17f",obj.d);
```

and you'll get:

```
Value stored in d is 15.50000000000035705
```